# Making my form responsive according the sprites

Tags: html, css

I can use all the help with making my contact form responsive according the eagle sprite I have on this page: http://demo.chilipress.com/epic3/
The idea is to have the eagle's mouth over the form while the screen gets resized. 
As you can see, the sprites are completely responsive and so is the form. However the form does not stick to the eagle's mouth when resizing.

HTML:

```
       <section id="two" class="window">
        <img src="assets/contact.jpg" alt="background image">
        <div id="sprite1_contact"></div>
        <div id="sprite2_contact"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="contact">
                <form>
                <fieldset class="name group">
                    <label for="name" class="name">Name</label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" required aria-required=”true” pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z]+"  title="firstname lastname"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="email group">
                    <label for="email" class="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required title="Submit a valid Email">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="phone group">
                    <label for="phone" class="phone">Telephone</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="(\+?\d[- .]*){7,17}" required title="Submit an international, national or local phone number"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="message group">
                    <label class="message">Message</label>
                    <input type="text" id="message" required/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="send group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="sendButton">
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </section>
```

CSS

```
#sprite1_contact{
background-image: url('sprite_contact2.png');
width: 35.2%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 7%;
background-position: 0 0;
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 32.3%;
z-index: 2;}

#sprite2_contact {
background-image: url('sprite_contact2.png');
width: 27.5%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 29%;
background-position: 0 27%;
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 35.8%;
z-index: 1;}

#content{
max-width: 50.694%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
border-radius: 13px;
width: 678px;
margin: 0 0 7.6% 25.9167%;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000000, 2px 2px 30px 1px rgba(199, 255, 100, 0.73);}

.contact{
width: 100%;
margin: 10px;}

fieldset{
border: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 1%;}

.name, .email, .message{
padding-right: 29px;}

label{
color: #d8d9de;
font-family:'apple_chancerychancery';
font-size: 1.2em;
padding-left: 10px;}

input{
margin-right: 50px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: left;
border-radius: 10px;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 240, 260, 0.5);}

#name, #email, #phone, #message{
float: right;  
color: #253c93;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px dotted #29FF00;
font-family: 'Calibri', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
width: 73%;}

#name{
width: 73.5%;}

textarea {vertical-align: top;}

div#inner-editor{
padding: 30px;}

#message{
padding-top: 10%;}

.sendButton{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
color: #d8d9de;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-family: 'apple_chancerychancery';
padding: 0.8% 4%;
border: none;
margin-left: 42%;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 9px rgba(199, 255, 100, 0.73), inset -2px -2px 9px rgba(199, 255, 100, 0.73);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 changes in the CSS:

```
#sprite2_contact {
    top: 0px !important;
}
```

just to overcome the top that is inline ..

and

```
#content {
    margin-top: 28%;
}
```

Well, you have already a margin property there, just place that afterwards so that the other is overwritten

I have set those changes this way, instead of changing yours, so the changes can be more easily seen and reverted

Comment: Not working for me. 
I took out the top that was inline and so I did not need to apply top: 0px !important. 

I did however apply margin-top but did not give the proper effect I need.

Comment: I want the form including it's fieldsets to be fully responsive and stick to the eagles mouth when I resize my screen.

Comment: I made a fiddle write after you suggested so. However, I am trying to add a new background first to the page and then I'll get back here with a fiddle. Thanks